# Error with Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am going through the Discover Meteor book and have come to the part of adding Iron Router.

I have used the `$ meteor add iron:router` and am now running the latest versions of meteor (1.1.0.2) and iron router (1.0.7). The microscope app being worked on still crashes giving the following errors:

```
The connection to ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/057/8aq0hvee/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. ddp.js:1344:0

TypeError: Template.__create__ is not a function iron-dynamic-template.js:416:37

TypeError: Parent is undefined meteor.js:225:4

TypeError: Iron.Layout is not a constructor iron-router.js:1475:19

Error: There are multiple templates named '__IronDefaultLayout__'. Each template needs a unique name. templating.js:59:0

TypeError: Layout is not a constructor iron_router.js:1617:17

TypeError: Package['iron:router'] is undefined global-imports.js:3:0

ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.layout.js:2:0

ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.post_item.js:2:0

ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.posts_list.js:2:0

ReferenceError: Router is not defined router.js:1:12

ReferenceError: Template is not defined post_item.js:1:12

ReferenceError: Template is not defined posts_list.js:1:12

ReferenceError: Router is not defined router.js:1:12

ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined posts.js:1:12

ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined main.js:1:12
```

Most posts for something like this say I need to use the `meteor add iron:router` instead of `mrt add iron:router`, however even after doing so, the app still keeps crashing.

Comment: Post the code. It is hard to tell from errors what is going on.